# Is there an AI function that can provide the definition of a word or phase with reasonably good accuracy?

Tags: nlp, gpt

I would like to make use of a software function which can provide the definition of a word or phrase. These words and phrases are in the realm of common knowledge - objects like "DVD player", or specific places like "Canary Islands".

I am pretty sure GPT-3 can do this because it's trained on the internet in general and Wikipedia, and it produces generally fluent language.

However, I was curious if someone has already written this function and provided it in some software library somewhere already.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this in NLP. Mind that it's not because GPT3 (or any model) is trained on the whole internet that it knows how to generate a definition. I think it would be a very complex task actually to infer a definition from examples of usage. Picking an existing definition is much easier of course, but then there's no need to involve any AI.